# Pig Python UDF failing in MapReduce mode

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

I have small Pig script where I call a Python UDF using the recently introducing StreamingUDF functionality:

```
REGISTER 'process_tweet.py' USING streaming_python AS process_tweet;
REGISTER /usr/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar

tweets = LOAD 'hbase://brand_tweets' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('data:json') AS (json:chararray);
tweets = LIMIT tweets 100;

tweets = foreach tweets generate flatten(process_tweet.extract(json)) as (userid:long, text: chararray);

dump tweets;
```

The Python function process_tweet.extract is basically just deserializing a JSON object (tweet), and returning some of it's values.

```
from pig_util import outputSchema
import json


    @outputSchema("(userid:long, text:chararray)")
    def extract(tweet):
        content = json.loads(tweet)
        return long(content['user']['id']), content['text']
```

When executed in local mode (pig -x local) the script runs without error and returns the expected output. In MapReduce mode, however, the job takes a very long time to run before it fails with the error messages below:

```
Backend error message
---------------------
AttemptID:attempt_1394221905204_0172_r_000000_1 Info:Error: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF)[tuple] - scope-7 Operator Key: scope-7) children: null at []]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:338)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:378)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:298)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.runPipeline(PigGenericMapReduce.java:464)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.processOnePackageOutput(PigGenericMapReduce.java:432)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.reduce(PigGenericMapReduce.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF.getControllerPath(StreamingUDF.java:268)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF.constructCommand(StreamingUDF.java:199)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF.startUdfController(StreamingUDF.java:163)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF.initialize(StreamingUDF.java:156)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF.exec(StreamingUDF.java:146)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:330)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextTuple(POUserFunc.java:369)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:333)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that StreamingUDF's are not supported on Hadoop 2.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3478

Comment: I am facing the same error:

    ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias c. Backend error : Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.StreamingUDF)[chararray] - scope-4 Operator Key: scope-4) children: null at []]: java.lang.NullPointerException

We are using Hadoop 1.0 – Hadoop version is -1.0.3

Can you please help.

Warm Regards,
Sumit